# How to install google test and google mock in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have given a task to study about google test and google mock. But I want to try out the codes in the book that I have. I went and look around for tutorials of how to install google test and google mock in eclipse on the net. But I can't find a windows base tutorials. Can you guide me in window base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a tool for managing C/C++ dependencies, its name is [biicode](http://www.biicode.com/)

Take a look at the [Getting Started C/C++ section](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/gettingstarted.html) (it's based on GTest example) and try the examples with [GTest and GMock](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/examples.html)

I think it'll help you start with Google Test library and GMock.

Disclaimer: I work in this company and we're dedicated to manage dependencies and build projects with tools such as Eclipse, MSVC, etc. I hope it helps you ;)